# How to make a reshaping layer in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

When I have data of shape [2,2,2], e.g.:

```
a = np.array([[(1,2), (3,4)],
              [(5,6), (7,8)]
              ])
```

And I want the layer to output [2,2], e.g.:

```
b = np.array([[1,0],
              [0,1]])
```

How do I build the layer? My current setup returns a shape of [2,2,1] and I cannot seem to be able to specify the dimensions in the units variable of the layer:

```
tf_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2, 2]) 

output = tf.layers.dense(tf_x, 1, tf.nn.relu) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())    
    pred = sess.run(output, {tf_x: a})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My current setup returns a shape of [2,2,1] and I cannot seem to be able to specify the dimensions in the units variable of the layer:

```
a = a.reshape(1, -1)

tf_x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, a.shape[-1]]) 

# now if you want the final array to have total 4 element, you can set it as number of output
output = tf.layers.dense(tf_x, 4, tf.nn.relu) 

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())    
    pred = sess.run(output, {tf_x: a})
pred = pred.reshape(2, 2)
```

Comment: This is just reshaping the data before and after processing, no? I thought maybe you could specify that within the layer. Anyways, thanks.

Comment: Not really, it maps the input array to a output array using a matrix. reshaping is to get the data into required shape. `output = tf.layers.dense(tf_x, 4, tf.nn.relu) ` here you are specifying number of element for output.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
b = tf.reshape(a, shape)
```

Comment: My problem with this is that logically the (a,b) in each row [(a1,b1), (a2,b2)] belong together, with the second variable b dependent on a (i.e. logically even if b1=b2, they are not equal if a1!=a2) . If I reshape it this way, it will look like [a1,b1,a2,b2], where the logical pairing of these two numbers might be lost, i.e. if b1=b2, the reshaped row will contain the same number two times even though they don't mean the same thing. Is this the correct way to reshape it?